# Request a data from table and display in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

My php code is this :

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result_set = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT points FROM total WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
$old_total = $row['points'];
$new_total = $old_total + $_REQUEST['total'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE total SET points = $new_total WHERE id = 1");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So now i need the $new_total to be shown on my html page, help me please.

---

This is the final code i used:

```
<?php include 'something.php'; ?>
<h3> <?php echo $new_total?> </h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this file in home page and then place this code  in home page you will be able to see the out put:

```
    <?php echo $new_total ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `echo` it in an appropriate place

```
echo $new_total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as `<?php echo $new_total ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply display this variable in html like `<h3> <?php echo $new_total?> </h3>.`

Answer (score 0):

include this php file in your new **html page**

and echo it something like this in your new **html page**  code:-

```
<?php 
      include "this.php";  /*your current php file name */ 
      echo $new_total;    /*print your new_total in html page */
?>
```

hope it will usefull.